# Receiving touchesBegan: on UIViewController - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have added a UITableView as a subview on my UITableView.
I have troubling 'passing through' touches on my UITableView (subview) to the view of my UIViewController (where my touchesBegan: method works as expected).

I have tried:

- Subclassing my UITableView and passing touchesBegan: to the superview from there
- pointInside: in superview
- hitTest: in subclassed tableView

Also: Disabling userInteraction on my tableView works, but of course, I still want to maintain the cellDidSelectRow.. functionality.

My Code implementation in ViewController:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan popup");
    if (!self.draggable) {
        //[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (!_moving) {
    //(touch.view == self || touch.view.superview == self) &&
        _moving = YES;
        _movingStartY = [touch locationInView:self.view].y;
        NSLog(@"moving popup");
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if (!self.draggable) {
        //[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    if (_moving) {
        NSLog(@"touchesMoved popup");
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        float offset = [touch locationInView:self.view].y - _movingStartY;
        if ([self.touchEventDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(popupNavigationBar:touchDidMoveWithOffset:)]) {
            [self.touchEventDelegate popupNavigationBar:self touchDidMoveWithOffset:offset];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.draggable) {
        //[super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    if (_moving) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        float offset = [touch locationInView:self.view].y - _movingStartY;
        [self movingDidEndWithOffset:offset];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.draggable) {
        //[self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }

    if (_moving) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        float offset = [touch locationInView:self.view].y - _movingStartY;
        [self movingDidEndWithOffset:offset];
    }
}

- (void)movingDidEndWithOffset:(float)offset
{
    _moving = NO;
    if ([self.touchEventDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(popupNavigationBar:touchDidEndWithOffset:)]) {
        [self.touchEventDelegate popupNavigationBar:self touchDidEndWithOffset:offset];
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Better if you also add what is your actual functionality?

Comment: Have updated my answer, The first NSlog never gets called if I touch the tableView, only if the superView is tapped.

Comment: have you tried calling the base class inside your touch began? eg: [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

Comment: @Amir.n3t yes, I already tried it, but no reaction :/